# How to make Regex for Windows Forms

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

Making **Windows Form** and needs to **validate** a username
which will be a **minimum of 4 characters and maximum of 15 characters long.** It will also allow hyphens and underscores as well as dots in the middle, but not at the start and neither at the end of the username. There may be no more than one hyphen, one underscore and one dot in a row. it should not take white spaces
**Examples of disallowed usernames:**

```
-aquib
_aquib
.aquibxyz
aquib.
99546521896   // should not allow only number. username should be alphanumeric or alphabetic
aquibxyz--qureshi
aquib__xyzqureshi
aquibqureshi-
aquib..qureshi
aquib_     // means no symbols will be there at end
```

Comment: And what have you tried? No downvote by the way...

Comment: Why must it be a regex? The first test is for length <= 15 chars, so performance is not an issue and writing a single line of code for every requirement makes the code more maintainable and easier to check than one mystique regular expression.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can make a single regex for that. Start with simple requirements:

```
/^[^\s._-]\S{2,13}[^\s._-]$/
```

That means 'a string should start from any character that is not a whitespace symbol, a dot, a hyphen or an underscore, followed by not fewer than 2 but not more than 13 non-whitespace characters, followed by any character that is not a whitespace symbol, a dot, a hyphen or an underscore'.

To decorate this with additional requirements, use lookaheads:

```
/^(?=[^-]*-?[^-]*$)(?=[^.][.]?[^.]*$)(?=[^_]*_?[^_]*$)[^\s._-]\S{2,13}[^\s._-]$/
```

The pattern is quite clear, I suppose: for each symbol that should be encountered only once, use a lookahead that says 'match any number of symbols that are not the checked one, then for the checked one (which is optional), then, again, for any number of symbols that are not the checked one, then the end of the string'.

```
(?=[^s]*s?[^s]*$)
```

The final part is checking that the string should not consist of numbers only:

```
(?!\d+$)
```

I wonder, though, why you want to do it with a single regex - and not a series of tests, which will be both more flexible and readable.

Comment: i have to use your 4 regex seperatley to acchive the task?